# Recursive relationship traversal and updates in SQLAlchemy + SQLModel?

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with SQLModel and I have a series of nested relationships.

I am working with SQLAlchemy ORM in Python and facing a challenge in handling nested relationships. I have a series of models with multiple levels of relationships, some being many-to-one and others many-to-many. My goal is to traverse these relationships to determine if any sub-relationships have changed when I create a new object graph.

As an example:

```
    # Many-to-Many relationship table between Book and Genre
    book_genre_table = Table('book_genre', Base.metadata,
        Column('book_id', Integer, ForeignKey('books.id')),
        Column('genre_id', Integer, ForeignKey('genres.id'))
    )

    class Author(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'authors'
        __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('name'),)

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String, unique=True)  # Unique constraint on the 'name' field

        # One-to-Many relationship with Book
        books = relationship('Book', back_populates='author')

    class Book(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'books'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        title = Column(String)
        author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('authors.id'))
        last_purchased_at = Column(DateTime)

        # Many-to-One relationship with Author
        author = relationship('Author', back_populates='books')

        # Many-to-Many relationship with Genre
        genres = relationship('Genre', secondary=book_genre_table, back_populates='books')

    class Genre(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'genres'
        __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('name'),)

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String, unique=True)  # Unique constraint on the 'name' field

        # Many-to-Many relationship with Book
        books = relationship('Book', secondary=book_genre_table, back_populates='genres')
```

These models all have uniqueness constraints.  In my code I accessing multiple data sources and then constructing the entire object graph before persisting.  One problem I'm having is determining if an object already exists in my database and therefore should be updated (e.g. the last_purchased_date) or if a new object should be created in persisted.  If I were just talking about doing that with a single Book instance, it would be easy enough to implement a `find_or_create` function, but the problem I'm encountering accurately tracking and managing changes in nested relationships.

The relationships are as follows:

Author to Book: Many-to-One
Book to Genre: Many-to-Many
Each Book also has a last_purchased_at timestamp which I need to update under certain conditions.

My specific challenges are:

- Identifying Changes in Relationships: When a new book is added or an existing book's details are updated (including changes in its genres), I need to identify these changes accurately.
- Handling Uniqueness Constraints: There are uniqueness constraints on Author.name and Genre.name. I need to handle scenarios where a new book might be associated with an existing author or genre.
- Efficiency Concerns: As the depth of relationships grows, I am concerned about the efficiency of traversing and comparing these nested objects.

So far I can't find any solutions online for recursively iterating through a SQLAlchemy object graph and checking each relationship to see 1) if it exists (in which case I'd want to grab the object that already exists and attach it to my in-memory object graph), 2) is it changed (and therefore needs to be updated), and 3) if it doesn't exist to create a new object.

If anyone has encountered this problem before or has any resources they could point me to, that would be greatly appreciated.

The solution I've been working towards looks like this:

```
from typing import Type, Any, Optional, Dict
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from sqlmodel import Session, SQLModel, Relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import RelationshipProperty
import pydantic
from sqlalchemy.orm import selectinload


def find_relationships(model: Type[SQLModel]) -> typing.List[str]:
    relationships = []
    for attr_name, attr_type in model.__annotations__.items():
        # Check if attr_type is a generic type (e.g., List, Optional)
        if isinstance(attr_type, typing._GenericAlias):
            # Check type arguments of the generic type
            for arg in typing.get_args(attr_type):
                if isinstance(arg, typing.ForwardRef) or (isinstance(arg, type) and issubclass(arg, SQLModel)):
                    relationships.append(attr_name)
                    break  # Found a relationship, no need to check other args
        elif isinstance(attr_type, type) and issubclass(attr_type, SQLModel):
            relationships.append(attr_name)

    return relationships


async def load_relationships(async_session: osiris.database.AsyncSession,
                             model_instance,
                             relationship_keys):
    options = [selectinload(getattr(model_instance.__class__, attr)) for attr in relationship_keys]
    stmt = select(model_instance.__class__).options(*options).where(model_instance.__class__.id == model_instance.id)
    result = await async_session.execute(stmt)
    return result.scalars().first()


async def find_existing_instance(async_session: osiris.database.AsyncSession, model, **kwargs):
    """
    Find an existing instance of a model based on provided attributes (kwargs).
    If found, return the instance; otherwise, return None.
    """
    stmt = select(model).where(
        *[getattr(model, key) == value for key, value in kwargs.items()]
    )
    result = await async_session.execute(stmt)
    instance = result.scalars().first()
    return instance


def find_unique_constraints(model: Type[SQLModel]) -> typing.List[typing.Union[sqlalchemy.UniqueConstraint, sqlalchemy.Column]]:
    unique_constraints = set()

    # Check for table-level unique constraints in __table_args__
    if hasattr(model, '__table_args__'):
        for arg in model.__table_args__:
            if isinstance(arg, sqlalchemy.UniqueConstraint):
                for column in arg:
                    unique_constraints.add(column.name)

    # Check for column-level unique constraints
    for _, attr in model.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(attr, sqlalchemy.Column) and attr.unique:
            unique_constraints.add(attr)

    return unique_constraints


async def find_or_create(async_session: osiris.database.AsyncSession, new_instance, recurse: bool = True):
    unique_constraint_keys = find_unique_constraints(new_instance.__class__)
    print(f"model: {new_instance.__class__}, unique_constraint_keys: {unique_constraint_keys}")
    search_fields = new_instance.model_dump(include=unique_constraint_keys)

    # Check for existing instance of the class based on unique constraints
    existing_instance = await find_existing_instance(async_session, new_instance.__class__, **search_fields)
    if existing_instance:
        print(f"Found existing instance: {existing_instance.id} for {existing_instance.__class__}")
        if recurse:

            # If found, load all relationships
            relationship_keys = find_relationships(new_instance.__class__)
            new_instance = await load_relationships(async_session, new_instance, relationship_keys)
            print(f"New instance is {new_instance.model_dump()}")
            existing_instance = await load_relationships(async_session, existing_instance, relationship_keys)
            print(f"Existing instance is {existing_instance.model_dump()}")
            for key in relationship_keys:
                new_attribute = getattr(new_instance, key, None)
                existing_attribute = getattr(existing_instance, key, None)

                # Check if new and existing attribute are lists
                if isinstance(new_attribute, list) and isinstance(existing_attribute, list):
                    if len(new_attribute) == 0 and len(existing_attribute) == 0:
                        continue
                    if len(new_attribute) > 0:
                        new_attribute_unique_constraint_keys = find_unique_constraints(new_attribute[0].__class__)
                        new_attribute_dicts = [item.model_dump(include=new_attribute_unique_constraint_keys) for item in new_attribute]
                    if len(existing_attribute) > 0:
                        existing_attribute_unique_constraint_keys = find_unique_constraints(existing_attribute[0].__class__)
                        existing_attribute_dicts = [item.model_dump(include=existing_attribute_unique_constraint_keys) for item in existing_attribute]

                    # Check if new attribute is a subset of existing attribute
                    for item_dict, item in zip(new_attribute_dicts, new_attribute):
                        if item_dict not in existing_attribute_dicts:
                            await find_or_create(async_session, item)
                else:
                    new_attribute_unique_constraint_keys = find_unique_constraints(new_attribute.__class__)
                    new_attribute_dict = new_attribute.model_dump(include=new_attribute_unique_constraint_keys)
                    existing_attribute_unique_constraint_keys = find_unique_constraints(existing_attribute.__class__)
                    existing_attribute_dict = existing_attribute.model_dump(include=existing_attribute_unique_constraint_keys)
                    if new_attribute_dict != existing_attribute_dict:
                        await find_or_create(async_session, new_attribute)

        await async_session.commit()
        await async_session.refresh(existing_instance)
        return existing_instance

    async_session.add(new_instance)
    await async_session.commit()
    await async_session.refresh(new_instance)

    if recurse:
        relationship_keys = find_relationships(new_instance.__class__)
        new_instance = await load_relationships(async_session, new_instance, relationship_keys)
        for key in relationship_keys:
            new_attribute = getattr(new_instance, key, None)
            if isinstance(new_attribute, list):
                for item in new_attribute:
                    await find_or_create(async_session, item)
            else:
                await find_or_create(async_session, new_attribute)

    return new_instance
```

But some issues are loading the relationships (inefficient), and committing through this async_session.

Comment: I had a hard time understanding how you got from your example models to the much more complicated functions below.  Are you trying to keep the entire object graph in memory for an extended period of time?

Comment: Or are you trying to sync a database with some 3rd party data source, like a CSV file or something?